# Troubleshooting "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket" when calling mysql_real_escape_string()

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting the error:

> Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Why do I get this error? The mysql_real_escape_string() works on all of my pages apart from one? Is it something to do with MySQL being on a different server to the PHP server - if so, how do I fix it?

```
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$fname = stripslashes($fname);
$fname = mysql_real_escape_string($fname);
```

Comment: Can you post the code in question?

Comment: @Tom why you call stripslashes($fname) before  mysql_real_escape_string()?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because you never call `mysql_connect()` before the use of `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

In order to use `mysql_real_escape_string()`, PHP must be connected to the database. In order to connect to the database, you must use `mysql_connect()`.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why does it need to call the database to execute that function?

Comment: The PHP code invokes the MySQL's library function to escape the strings, so in order for the code to invoke the library function, it must be connected first.

Comment: It calls a MySQL library function to do the escaping. It is not done in PHP directly.

Comment: @Spencer Good question.  It's because the escaping depends on the character set used by the server ( see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-real-escape-string.html )